# JSON encoding and decoding #2

Tags: c#, json, encoding

I have been working with JSON REST service for Elastic Search a lot lately. The most common problem I have come across is the encoding and coding of the HTML in the JSON.

At this point I have tried a combination of `htmlencode` and `htmldecode` but some of the characters come out as funny.

What is the best way of handling this HTML?

Comment: can you be more specific?  what does the response look like and what are you using to do the JSON parsing?

Comment: Can you share a sample JSON string that you're trying to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JSON.NET for encoding and decoding and it seems to work without any problems. I would highly recommend this for anybody looking to work with JSON.